# How to read and write from a file?

Tags: java

The goal is to read from the sample MonthTemps.txt and write to the two files(HotDays.txt, ColdNights.txt). With the below code I do not get any compilation errors, however the two files that are suppose to be written to are still blank. I have to do this specifically with File and PrintWriter.

Sample:

*Day High Low*

1 78 52

2 79 55

3 86 62

4 87 62

5 85 61

6 89 65

7 69 60

8 72 59

9 67 62

10 70 63

11 74 58

12 58 48

13 52 38

14 58 35

15 59 42

16 48 34

17 42 27

18 46 24

19 53 37

20 44 28

21 41 27

22 46 37

23 59 46

24 67 54

25 64 37

26 45 31

27 54 31

28 48 39

29 44 38

30 46 30

31 57 28

*Current Code*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MJackson_Lab05 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //Declare values. I try to initialize at 0 because it gives an error.
    int day, lowTemp, highTemp;

    //Open sample
    File MonthTemp = new File("MonthTemps.txt");
    if (!MonthTemp.exists()){                   //Check for existance
        System.out.println("File not found!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(MonthTemp);   //Scanner object

    //Create new files
    PrintWriter hotD = new PrintWriter("HotDays.txt");
    PrintWriter coldN = new PrintWriter("ColdNights.txt");

    //read data from scanner.
    while (myInput.hasNext()){
        day = myInput.nextInt();
        lowTemp = myInput.nextInt();
        highTemp = myInput.nextInt();

        if (highTemp >= 80)
            hotD.println(day + "  " + highTemp + "  " + lowTemp);


        if (lowTemp < 30)
            coldN.println(day + "  " + highTemp + "  " + lowTemp);





    }


    myInput.close();
    hotD.close();
    coldN.close();

    System.exit(0);

        }
    }
```

Comment: How do I get my question off hold? I am very new to this and really running out of time. I have reviewed the answer and I have heard nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To read from a file you need to:

```
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader("path_of_your_file");
BufferReader br = new BufferReader(is);
```

and then use a while loop to read every line until there's a valid input using:

```
br.readLine();
```

To write on the file you have to do the same thing using an `oputputStreamReader("output_path")` instead of `inputStreamReader("input_path")` and the `write()` method.

Thats the simpliest way, of course it depends on your final purpouse

Answer (score 1):

You read all the data, but not store, you should put conditions to while cycle

```
    while (myInput.hasNext()){
        day = myInput.nextInt();
        lowTemp = myInput.nextInt();
        highTemp = myInput.nextInt();

        if (highTemp >= 80)
            hotD.println(day + "  " + highTemp + "  " + lowTemp);
        else if (lowTemp < 30)
            coldN.println(day + "  " + highTemp + "  " + lowTemp);
    }
```